# Mixing two sqlite queries trying to get the total quantity

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to fetch the team goals for, using one query not two.

How can I do this if:

**This query fetch all home goals for the team:**

```
SELECT SUM(home_goals) FROM match WHERE home_team_id = ?
```

**This query fetch all away goals for the team:**

```
SELECT SUM(away_goals) FROM match WHERE away_team_id = ?
```

I want to do it the total team goals for in one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```sql
SELECT SUM(goals)
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(home_goals) AS goals
  FROM match
  WHERE home_team_id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUM(away_goals)
  FROM match
  WHERE away_team_id = 1
  ) a
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/bf3f7/3)</kbd>

Or using case:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
      WHEN home_team_id = 1
        THEN home_goals
      WHEN away_team_id = 1
        THEN away_goals
      ELSE 0
      END) AS goals
FROM match
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/bf3f7/6)</kbd>

Comment: @JohnB. True.. Union all is probably safer.

Comment: Yes, You can check with this example based on your example (I have added two records that fails with union and not with union all): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6b60b/1